# firebase storage cannot delete file with full url

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

i have full url passed into this line:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(fileUrl).delete();
```

however when i try to run it there is an error

```
E/StorageException(31877): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(31877): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(31877):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(31877): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(31877): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
E/flutter (31877): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.
E/flutter (31877): #0      MethodChannelReference.delete (package:firebase_storage_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_reference.dart:37:7)
E/flutter (31877): <asynchronous suspension>
```

i am 100% sure the file exists in storage and the url is correct..

full url :
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rent-bf2c1.appspot.com/o/image2021-07-23%2019%3A42%3A52.657330?alt=media&token=24fb6115-c69b-47d7-b98e-475b4243bf14

Comment: How are you getting the file url?

Comment: I copy the url from firebase directly

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual URL you are using.  We have no way to know whether you're using a correct value otherwise, and the error message seems quite explicit in saying the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated full url

Comment: That URL does seem to exist, and is of the right format. Are you sure you've initialized your Firebase code for the correct project? If you've used the configuration from a different project, that would explain why it can't find the URL on *this* project.

Comment: Yes, 100% sure setup is correct as i can do upload image in the same function, while delete is not working. Is it possible due to the rule settings? I see read & write, should i add “delete” ?